# ImportError Only in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, importerror

When I try importing functions and classes that I've created in Python scripts into a Jupyter Notebook, I get import errors. However, when I run the same code in a regular script rather than in a notebook, it runs without a problem.

All three files are in the same directory:

First, I have my_function_script.py, which defines functions.

```
def my_function():
    pass
```

Second, I have my_class_script, which both imports the functions defines classes:

```
from my_function_script import my_function

class my_class():
    pass
```

When I try to run the below import script in a Jupyter Notebook, I get an ImportError.

```
from my_class_script import my_class
```

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-8f2c4c886b44> in <module>
----> 1 from my_class_script import my_class

~\my_directory\my_class_script.py in <module>
      5 
----> 6 from my_function_script import my_function

ImportError: cannot import name 'my_function' from 'my_function_script' (C:\Users\my_directory\my_function_script.py)
```

I believe that the problem is specific to the Jupyter Notebook for two reasons. First, I've confirmed that both my_function_script.py and my_class_script.py can run in the terminal without error. Second, when I take the same line that causes the Jupyter Notebook to error and run it in a regular Python script, it runs without error.

I have Windows, and I don't have multiple environments or versions of Python.

Comment: Does `import my_function_script` work?

Answer (score 0):

you can add to the Python path at runtime:

```py
# some_file.py
import sys
# insert at 1, 0 is the script path (or '' in REPL)
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file
```

Comment: Same as above. I tried this and got the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

this usually happens when your jupyter notebook does not point to the correct directory for importing
one way to fix this would be to change the working directory in jupyter notebook

```
import os
os.chdir('path/to/python/scripts/directory')
from my_class_script import my_class
```

another way to do this is using UNIX commands directly in jupyter notebook

```
cd /path/to/python_script_directory
from my_class_script import my_class
```

make sure you **dont** put the `cd` command and import statement in the same notebook block

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and got the same error. For what it's worth, I noticed that the last line of the error contains the correct path whether or not I run this.

Comment: I have had similar issues with jupyter while using windows which I was never able to fix or figure out the reason for. Not that you should, but as a recommendation i would suggest using linux kernel for development. its easy to do with [dual boot](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) or with [VMware](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html). one of the linux flavours I am a fan of is elementary OS

Comment: did you try doing "\\" in place of all "\" for the path. "\" works as an [special escape character](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp) in windows and the path is not valid. another reason why I switched to linux.